# Laravel production error using Guzzle HTTP to get URL status code

Tags: laravel, discord, guzzle

I am running into an issue where I'm getting the following error in my `laravel.log` file.

```
[2020-12-20 13:43:43] production.ERROR: URI must be a string or UriInterface
```

However my code works in development, which is super weird. I'm trying to figure out why this isn't working and i'm just really at a loss and no amount of googling or searching here has answered my question as to why in development vs production this error is occuring.

Heres my function:

```
/**
 * Returns the user avatar or the placeholder avatar
 * depending on the Discord Status Code
 *
 * @param \App\Models\Auth\User $user
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|mixed|string
 */
public static function getUserAvatar(\App\Models\Auth\User $user) {
    $client = new Client();

    try {
        $response = $client->head($user->avatar);
    } catch(BadResponseException $e) {
        return "https://dummyimage.com/128x128/888ea8/ebedf2.png?text=No+Image+Found";
    }

    if($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
        return $user->avatar;
    } else {
        return "https://dummyimage.com/128x128/888ea8/ebedf2.png?text=No+Image+Found";
    }
}
```

The main functionality is this... whenever a User logs in, their avatar updates from discord (using socialite as the login provider). However if the user changes their avatar in discord, but hasn't logged into our site in a while, that avatar link will just go dead as discord no longer wants to serve it. So the avatar link returns a 404 code. I'm basically just trying to handle this 404 code and not display a broken image on the site. Rather it just be a placeholder image instead.

Edit: When i die and dump on `$user->avatar` I get the following result:

[image: Die and Dump Image Avatar]

I've also tried the following as well to no avail:

`$response = $client->request('GET', (string) $user->avatar, ['allow_redirects' => false, 'verify' => false]);`

Thanks.

Comment: You are not accounting for a scenario when the $user is null or $user->avatar is null. As per the stack trace in the log file which is the line that causes the error

Comment: `$avatar = $user->avatar ?? "https://dummyimage.com/128x128/888ea8/ebedf2.png?text=No+Image+Found"` and then `$response = $client->head($avatar)` - try

Comment: the head will also work but are you sure you have values for all the $user->avatar & none of them has no or null value

Comment: @Donkarnash The value in the database is always going to have something. Thats how the code is written. It will always be the discord image. It will never be null as that field is required by the database. What the code is trying to do is check if the discord image is valid. After a user changes their avatar in discord, discord themselves deletes the image from their servers. Which then breaks the link and returns a 404. So, I'm basically trying to make sure that the image link is valid, and if it returns a 404 then it should just use the placeholder image instead.

Comment: Thats why this is confusing because i've done a die and dump before guzzle request and after, and the $user->avatar is returning the discord image link. So, its not null. Its definitely a string. Again this happens only in production, and not in development. I've checked my .env file to make sure everything was good, and even for a brief minute changed the env file on the production side to development settings, thinking it was the env file, and it still gave this error. So I'm truly at a loss on what to check for next.

Comment: do you know at which error is happening you can use $e->getLine() to get the error line when you push the error on logs

Comment: Also I want to confirm is the image url your request uri, are you sure, shouldn't it be like you should pass the image as multipart to the request url, also show the discord api which you are trying to call to update the image